# python-pandas-changing the default x as index to columns instead

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following as my code with the following graph displaying
[image]

[image]

Problem is, I wanted to compare each attribute(mean age, age amount etc) next to
each other. By default, pandas takes x as the index. How do I change it to take column names instead(Then there will be 3 comparisons, one for each attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use transpose with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df.T.plot.bar()
```